# How do I measure my coffin?

Tags: xcoffins

I'm experimenting with [xcoffins](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xcoffins) for a cover page (and enjoying myself immensely, BTW, what an ace package).

What I'm trying to to at this moment is fit a logo, some horizontal white space, and a coloured horizontal bar nicely into `\textwidth`

In my code, below, although the calculation of the length of the horizontal bar works nicely, it seems a bit clunky and 20th-century. I'm especially worried there might be significant overhead in `\settowidth{\worki}{\TypesetCoffin{\logo}}`. Can anyone suggest a cleaner, more ``modern'' way of doing it?

As a supplementary question: are there any plans to add coffin-specific measuring tools to xcoffins? Perhaps something along the lines of `\CoffinWidth{<coffin>}`, for example?

PS: I appreciate that xcoffins is work-in-progress and that the interface may still be a bit malleable...

Here's my M(ish)WE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}
\semiisopage
\checkandfixthelayout
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcoffins}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\NewCoffin \result
\SetHorizontalCoffin \result {}

\NewCoffin \logo
\SetHorizontalCoffin \logo {\includegraphics[height=2in]{mylogo}}

\NewCoffin \ruleh
\newlength{\worki}
\newlength{\workii}
\settowidth{\worki}{\TypesetCoffin{\logo}}
\setlength{\workii}{\textwidth}
\addtolength{\workii}{-5pt}
\addtolength{\workii}{-\worki}
\SetHorizontalCoffin \ruleh  {\color{blue}\rule{\workii}{1pc}}

\JoinCoffins \result \logo
\JoinCoffins \result[\logo-vc,\logo-r] \ruleh[vc,l](5pt,0pt)

\noindent
\TypesetCoffin \result
\end{document}
```

Comment: Feature requests always welcome! Rules are something that Frank Mittelbach has mentioned as needing attention, for example. I take it that the idea here is that the rule is to take up the 'rest' of the space?

Comment: Yes, Joseph, spot on (a vertical version might be nice, too). I'm sure I can think up more challenging examples, though, once I really get my teeth into it...

Comment: I'm expecting a wealth of amusingly titled questions related to `xcoffins`. Good times.

Comment: @Joseph when speaking of size, maybe a more generalized enquiry possibility would be useful too? E.g., `\CoffinSize[<pair of points denoted by poles>]` or something along those lines. Brent, it would be great if you would collect thoughts and feature requests when you play along with nails and planks :-)

Comment: @FrankMittelbach It's more of a 'inter-handle length', but we can certainly add it (looks quite easy).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\setlength{\worki}{\wd\logo}
```

A coffin name is also the name of the box register that contains it. It probably is not the "modern" way to do it, and perhaps **xcoffins** might have an interface for it.

If you want something "modern", then these commands can be defined:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\WidthOfCoffin}{m}{ \box_wd:N #1 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\HeightOfCoffin}{m}{ \box_ht:N #1 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\DepthOfCoffin}{m}{ \box_dp:N #1 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

so you can say

```
\setlength{\worki}{\WidthOfCoffin{\logo}}
```

Comment: The question is partly where does 'design' end and 'programming' begin (at which point you'd use `\box_wd:N` and the `\coffin_...` functions).

Comment: It may not be modern, but it's already a lot crisper than mine. Thanks.

Comment: @JosephWright: That's the eternal riddle. I think the divide is between "users" and "programmers", but I admit that in TeX that's also a bit blurred.

Comment: Maybe `\WidthOf{\logo}`?

Comment: +1 +Tick --- Nice one, Enrico. Grazie. I've even managed to put it straight into the sums without its own length variable: `\addtolength{\worki}{-\WidthOfCoffin{\logo}}`